# Django Post being called after view is processed

Tags: python, django

I am creating a forum where users can edit topics. When a user changes a topics title the slug for the topic is changed. When I post the changes to the topic the slug correcting middleware triggers and redirects me to back to the same editing page instead of letting me redirect to the topic itself. It seems django processes the view first and then calls post with the old url causing my changes to be saved but me not ending up in the right place. For example if I hit post without changing anything I am redirected where I should go. How do I fix this?

```
# middleware.py
class TopicSlugMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if (request.resolver_match and 'topic_slug' in request.resolver_match.kwargs):
            try:
                topic_slug = request.resolver_match.kwargs['topic_slug']

                topic_pk = int(topic_slug.split('-')[0])
                topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_pk)

                if (topic.slug != topic_slug):
                    return redirect(reverse(request.resolver_match.url_name, kwargs={'topic_slug': topic.slug}))
            except:
                raise Http404('The topic you are looking for does not exist')

        return response

# views.py
class EditTopicView(View):
    template_name = 'forums/edit_topic.html'

    def get(self, request, topic_slug):
        topic = Topic.objects.get(slug=topic_slug)

        if (request.user.profile.role.can_modify_topics or request.user == topic.started_by):
            if (request.user.profile.role.can_modify_topics):
                form = EditMoveTopicForm(instance=topic)
            else:
                form = NewTopicForm(instance=topic)
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'topic': topic, 'form': form})
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied('You do not have permission to modify this topic')

    def post(self, request, topic_slug):
        topic = Topic.objects.get(slug=topic_slug)

        if (request.user.profile.role.can_modify_topics or request.user == topic.started_by):
            if (request.user.profile.role.can_modify_topics):
                form = EditMoveTopicForm(request.POST)
            else:
                form = NewTopicForm(request.POST)

            if (form.is_valid()):
                topic.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
                topic.tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']
                topic.save()
                return redirect('/topics/' + topic.slug)
            else:
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'topic': topic, 'form': form})
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied('You do not have permission to modify this topic')
```